# In webview android, video is copied into the application data but will not play

Tags: java, android

My video is not playing on my android device, however the video is present in the package folder. The video is copied from my Asset folder.

`public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
private static final String TAG = "Copying File or Folder";

```
//Shared Preference
private String appName = "com.example.nadeemstc.webviewvideo";
private SharedPreferences pref;
private Editor editor;

//WebView Variables
private JsHandler _jsHandler;
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !view.hasFocus()) {
                view.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(appName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    //pref = getSharedPreferences(appName,0);
    // pref.getBoolean("flag",true);
    Boolean b = (pref.getBoolean(appName, false));
    Log.d("BgCopy", "Boolean Data is " + b);
    if (b == false) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute("Nadeem");
    } else if (b == true) {
        Log.d("BgCopy", "Folder Already Exists, do Not Copy");
        initWebView();
    }
}

private void initWebView() {

    //Tell the WebView to enable javascript execution.
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));

    //Set whether the DOM storage API is enabled.
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //setBuiltInZoomControls = false, removes +/- controls on screen
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 8);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    _jsHandler = new JsHandler(this, myWebView);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(_jsHandler, "JsHandler");

    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // these settings speed up page load into the webview
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    // load the main.html file that kept in assets folder
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

}
private void copyAssets(String path) {
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = getAssets().list(path);
        for (String fileName: files) {
            Log.d("CopyAsset", "file / folder name " + fileName);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (files.length == 0) {
        copyFile(path);
    } else {
        File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            copyAssets(path + "/" + files[i]);
        }
    }
    Log.d("CopyAssets ", "Done" + path + "is at " + files);
    doneCopy();
}
private void copyFile(String filename) {
    InputStream in = null;
    filename = "rah.mp4";
    File file;
    OutputStream out = null;

    try { in = getAssets().open(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR WITH out = new FileOutputStream(file);");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    //        int read;
    //        try {
    //            while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
    //                out.write(data, 0, read);
    //            }
    //            in.close();
    //            out.flush();
    //            out.close();
    //        } catch (Exception e) {
    //            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    //        }
    byte[] data;
    try {
        data = new byte[ in .available()]; in .read(data);
        out.write(data); in .close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void doneCopy() {
    Log.d("BgCopy", "Done Copying Files");
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask < String, Long, Boolean > {
    ProgressDialog progress;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String...files) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        copyMe(files[0]);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "Check The Boolean data ");
        progress.dismiss();
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(appName, true);
        editor.commit();
        initWebView();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long...values) {
        progress.setMessage("Transferred " + values[0] + " bytes");
    }


    private void copyMe(String si) {
        copyAssets(si);
    }

}
```

}`